# How to align left, in center the text?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this site:

[link](http://dg-design.ch/bagel/)

On this moment there are 3 articles that are aligned in the middle.
Are positioned in the center but want to be aligned left, but the center of the container...

**CODE HTML:**

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-height">
                        <div class="text-box-right slideInRight animated">
                            <div class="title-home">LE BAGEL</div>

                            <div class="content-home"><p>est l’essence même de l’inspiration de la maison.<br>
Bagel House Café vous propose un pain unique, directement importé<br>
des Usa puis transformé dans nos cuisines.<br>
Ce pain à la forme si spéciale vous réserve bien des surprises…<br>
Choisissez-le nature, au sésame, au pavot, müesli, sans gluten ou<br>
encore laissez-vous tenter par le fameux “everything”.</p>
</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

**CODE CSS:**

```
.col-height{
  height: 528px;
  display: table;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 17pt;
}

.col-height div{
  width: 100%;
}

.title-home{
  font-size: 32pt;
  font-family: Myridad pro;
  color: #2a2b30;
}
```

Can you please help me solve this problem?
I hope I was able to explain well what they want to do

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your stylesheet. a simple `text-align:left` will do.

To make the content in the middle of the container you will need to set a width for the `p` and set `margin:auto`

```
.content-home p
{
 text-align:left;
 width:70%;
 margin:auto;
}
```

Result will be like this

[image]

Comment: yes but only remain in the center ... it must be left but in the middle of the container

Answer (score 0):

just add `text-left` to `<p>` tag:

```
<p class="text-left">
```

Comment: yes but only remain in the center ... it must be left but in the middle of the container

Comment: means ? i didn't get you

Comment: if you want label also align in left then put `text-left` in your ` <div class="text-box-right slideInRight animated">` tag. i.e. ` <div class="text-box-right slideInRight animated text-left">`

Answer (score 0):

```
.text-box-right p {
    text-align:left.
}
```

I hope it helps!